# RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional tensor, but got 2-dimensional tensor for argument

Tags: python, nlp, allennlp

I have two tensors names: 'wy' and 'x', both of them with size 8:

```
wy= tensor([[ 74.2090, -92.9444,  45.2677, -38.4132, -39.8641,  -6.9193,  67.4830,
     -80.1534]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)

x= tensor([[ 70.,  77., 101.,  75.,  40.,  83.,  48.,  73.]])
```

Now, I want to do bmm to multiply x * wy as follow:

```
 xWy = x.bmm(Wy.unsqueeze(2)).squeeze(3)
```

I got an error:

```
  RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional tensor, but got 2-dimensional tensor for argument #1 'batch1' (while checking arguments for bmm)
```

8*8 should be possible. but I don't know why I got this error every time.

any help, please!

Comment: So you want `(1, 8) * (8, 1)` that results to a scalar?

Comment: Yes. That what I try to do

Comment: Alright, see my answer below then!

Comment: This has nothing to do with AllenNLP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bmm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bmm.html) stands for **batch** matrix-matrix product. So it expects **both** tensors with a batch dimension (i.e., 3D as the error says).

For single tensors, you want to use [`mm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mm.html) instead. Note that [`Tensor.mm()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.mm.html) also exists with the same behaviour.

```
x.mm(wy.transpose(0, 1))
```

```
tensor([[-5051.9199]])
```

Or better, for two 1D tensor you can use [`dot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.dot.html) for dot product.

```
# Or simply do not initialise them with an additional dimension. Not needed.
x.squeeze().dot(wy.squeeze())
```

```
tensor(-5051.9199)
```